# signin user upon clicking the link in email automatically in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, single-sign-on

I have a `User` model in my `rails` application. which is a "devise" model. i have one form called "user-info" form this form can be available once the user logs into the system.

i have one `admin` login in which an `admin` can send the `link` to the user `email` like fill the "user info" by clicking a `button`. once the user clicks the button i want the user to login into the system `automatically` without redirecting to the login page. and should be `navigated` to the `user-info` form.

i have an idea of sending query string parameters in the url like email = "x@gmail.com "&& form = "user_info". but once the user clicks on this what needs to be implemented to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can use the tokens to log in or to hit arbitrary pages that need authentication, even with cURL. If you look in `config/initializers/devise.rb`, there should be a line that says something like:

```
config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token
```

Whatever the name of the `token_authentication_key` is should match what you put as the query or form parameter in your request. You used `authentication_token` in your example, not sure if you changed devise.rb to match that or not.

If you want to figure out how things are working internally, I would try `git clone git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git` and search for the methods you need clarification of.

Here are some sample cURL requests (I made a custom Users::SessionsController that extends Devise::SessionsController and overrides the create method to handle JSON.)

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      end
      format.json do
        render :json => { :response => 'ok', :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token }.to_json, :status => :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then the cURL requests I gave:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json' -d 'user[email]=example@example.com&user[password]=password'
-> {"response":"ok","auth_token":"ABCDE0123456789"}

curl -L 'http://localhost:3000/profile?auth_token=ABCDE0123456789'
-> got page that I wanted that needs authentication
```

Comment: i want this functionality to send emails explicitly to the user's who did not fill the form. not for every user who signs up into the system

Comment: how can user directly signin on click link on email without entering password?

Comment: @John check my updated answer. You need to create authtoken and send it to email with link

Comment: but the password in the database is the encrypted password in devise. i can 't send the ecrypted password. i want to login only by using user name. like signin (User.find_by_email("x@gmail.com"))

Comment: no need to send password. you have to generate the auth_token and send the auth_token in link and then signin the user using auth_token

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Simple Token Authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) gem, it is well known to generate the authentication token and to be sent by email to the users you would like to have this authentication. please follow the setup instruction.